# C# Find Name in list (userinput) gets error

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to C# and I want to find my objects name in the list.

This is my code:

```
"class Wares
{
    string wareName;
    float warePrice, wareWeight;
    int wareStatus;

    List<Wares> warelist = new List<Wares>();



    public Wares(string WareName, float WarePrice, float WareWeight, int WareStatus)
    {

        this.wareName = WareName;
        this.warePrice = WarePrice;
        this.wareWeight = WareWeight;
        this.wareStatus = WareStatus;


        warelist = new List<Wares>();


    }

    public float Wareprice { get; set; }
    public float Wareweight { get; set; }
    public int Warestatus { get; set; }

    public string Desc()
    {

        string description = $"Denna vara heter {wareName} och kostar {warePrice}kr den väger {wareWeight}kg och det finns {wareStatus}st i lager";  

        return description;
    }

}

"public void FindInList()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What do you want to find?");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        warelist.Contains(userinput);

    }"
```

"

Warelist is my list. But I get the error cannot convert string to Namespace.Wares

My plan is to check if the list has the user input then add a possibility to remove the item.

Answer (score 0):

The `Contains` method checks to see if the provided object exists in the `List`. That means it expects an object of the same type that the list contains - it's not going to read your mind and search through each of those object's variables as well.

To do what you want as concise as you're trying to do it, you'll need LINQ:

```
warelist.Any(ware => ware.wareName == userInput);
```